# StoreKit multiple transactions

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, storekit

I'm stucked solving problem with In-App Purchases using StoreKit framework for Mac OS. The problem is this:

1) I call addPayment method when purchase started

2) Then updatedTransactions method called twice with transaction state SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing. And after second call [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions count] returns 2.

3) When purchase completed updatedTransactions called third time with transaction state SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased. And [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions count] returns 3.

4) Then I finishTransaction with state SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased. But in defaultQueue still remain two transactions with SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing. They alive till the app terminates. When I launch app again the problem repeats.

Why so many transactions for only one addPayment call? And how this problem can be solved?

Comment: You have to show some code or you can check my answer to this question which seams similar to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167286/in-app-purchase-ios-sending-more-transactions-than-needed/34241584#34241584

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call finishTransaction method after any of the below transaction state :

1) SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased

2) SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed

3) SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

Calling finishTransaction: on a transaction removes it from the queue.